# fatal error: dtls-support-conf.h: No such file or directory - Contiki-Ng, Cooja

Tags: gcc, simulation, ubuntu-22.04, cooja, contiki-ng

I am trying to run:

```
make TARGET=native client
```

in this directory:
`:~/contiki-ng/bpmac-master$`

But I am receiving this error:

```
  MKDIR     build/native/obj/.deps
  CC        client.c
In file included from client.c:31:
../os/net/security/tinydtls/tinydtls.h:35:10: fatal error: dtls-support-conf.h: No such file or directory
   35 | #include "dtls-support-conf.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [../Makefile.include:519: build/native/obj/client.o] Error 1
```

However, I checked the tinydtls.h file and it's available but I don't know why this error message is upper.

I am running the code as described in this repo https://github.com/fkie-cad/bpmac

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exmiI.png)

I tried to check the file directory and it's correct.